# Ubuntu: Error resizing partition while resizing partition of a Virtualbox VM running Ubuntu (Host is Windows10)

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, resize, udisks

I am trying to resize (from 20 to 270 GB) the hard disk of a Ubuntu OS running inside a VM (Virtualbox) that runs on Windows 10.

By following the instructions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234803/1342430) , I have with powered off my VM and run on my Windows 10 Powershell:

```
C:\Users\Bob> C:\"Program Files"\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyhd C:\Users\Bob\"VirtualBox VMs"\Tommaso_Ubuntu01\Tommaso_Ubuntu01.vdi --resize 270000
```

and I sussessfully get

```
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

so that when I check the settings of my VM on my Virtualbox panel I see:

[Virtualbox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpcF5.jpg)

then I go on following the steps in the thread: I start my VM, go to

Applications (square of 9 points in the bottom bar) > Disks > Hard Disk (left side bar)

then

select `Partition 3` (the partition that I previously sized to 21) > gears button > resize > set partition to 270 GB

but I get:

> **Error resizing partition**
>
> error resizing partition /dev/sda3: Failed to partition size on device
> '/-dev/sda/' (Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.)
> (udisk-error-quark,0)

What's the problem? How can I solve it?

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UszsI.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED

By following [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/345766/1342430), I installed GParted,

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

a pop-up opened up asking if I wanted to fix the unallocated free space (that I gof from the operation on powershell) > answered `don't fix`

selected the `partition3` (that I previously allocated to 20GB)

resize the selected partition:

- set `new size` to `260 GB`, set `Align` to `None`.
- clicked `apply all operations`

the same pop-up of before popped up, and this time I answered with `fix`.

The operation finished and I verified this time the VM got the change:

by tiping

```
df -h
```

the resized partition is returned among the others.