# Gparted unalocated space: “Unable to satisfy all the constraints on the partition”

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I know this question has already been adressed in several posts like here:
[unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316610/unable-to-satisfy-all-constraints-on-the-partition) or there [Gparted Error "Unable to satisfy all the constraints on the partition"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611892/gparted-error-unable-to-satisfy-all-the-constraints-on-the-partition). And I'm willing to use the fixparts software, but it says on every answer that I should be very careful using it and I don't really understand careful about what exactly.

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 14.04/Windows7 and recently freed some space in the Windows partition to extend the Ubuntu one (using easeus). After that I used the Boot repair tool to fix the boot. Finally, I can't reallocate it since Gparted is seeing the whole SSD as unallocated...

Here's my gparted error message:
[image]

Here's the `fdisk -l` return

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x56251d6b
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *       81920    25710591    12814336   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda3        25710592   253602089   113945749    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       376176639   500117503    61970432+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       376176640   433166335    28494848   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       433166336   500117503    33475584   82  Linux swap / Solaris

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 363376 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xcbcc2d95

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 363376 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xcbcc2d94

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I read on some posts that there should be some space (usually 1 or 2 Mb) between each logical partition to store the EBR. Unfortunately I don't know if this is really my problem nor how to fix it safely without Gparted.

I don't really know what more to add. Please, let me know if I'm missing something here and if "Fixparts" is the way to go.

Thanks!

Comment: `fdisk` doesn't support GPT partitioning. You have to use `gdisk`  to get accurate info for sdb and sdc, however that doesn't explain what happened to sda and why gparted refuses to handle it. I suggest that you begin by booting into Windows and running Chkdsk on all your windows partitions as suggested by @oldfred in a comment on this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/611892/gparted-error-unable-to-satisfy-all-the-constraints-on-the-partition You don't mention your version of Windows but you should also  http://superuser.com/questions/957081/how-to-enable-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10

Comment: what version of gparted are you using?

Comment: Do you have ~250 GB of free space on one of the 3 TB drives you have installed?

Comment: Hi! I solved my problem!
So:


1) Dualboot systems requires an MBR partition. Hence fdisk and not gdisk. sdb and sdc are only data drives (and they both are housing a 3T Basic Data Partition).


2) Windows7, beginning of the second paragraph :)


3) My problem came from the Swap partition sda6. Too close from the previous one. It became "obvious" using Fixparts because the partition was omitted. So I rewrote the MBR partition without the Swap using Fixparts again. From there Gparted (v0.18.0) was back and allowed to modify the partitions with a bit of work.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Since you found your answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/611892/gparted-error-unable-to-satisfy-all-the-constraints-on-the-partition you should upvote that answer so that others with the same problem are able to find the solution.

Comment: I just did but it's just not displayed since I don't have the 15 points of reputation yet :)

Comment: My apologies for forgetting about the 15 point requirement.  No worries, I already did that for you.

Comment: No problem and thanks again for taking time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

If it can be of some help for any other user:
My problem came from the Swap partition sda6. Too close from the previous one. It became "obvious" using Fixparts because the partition was omitted. So I rewrote the MBR partition without the Swap using Fixparts again. From there Gparted (v0.18.0) was back and allowed to modify the partitions